# Understanding Specifics of What ReadAsync is doing in ADO.NEt

Tags: c#, ado.net

Consider the following code using ADO.NET:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
  // at this point sw has elapsed for 10s

  while (await reader.ReadAsync())
  {

  }

  // at this point sw has elapsed for 15s
}
```

I understand that the 10s spent in `ExecuteReaderAsync` was time running the query.

What exactly is the 5s spent reading the results?

- Is it only time sending the data over the network?
- Is any of that impacted by the query (like a poor query taking longer to stream results)?
- What could I do to speed up the 5s spent reading? Improve network speed, or something else?

I am trying to understand at a fairly deep level what all impacts the time spent reading.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know with a lot of async work, by adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` you can speed up many, nearly the vast majority, of cases, so Context awaiting/switching is definitely one part of it. I don't understand it very deeply, but here is a fairly dense [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) that goes into it

Answer (score 1):

The time waited at `ExecuteReaderAsync` is mainly for the following:

- Time to send the request to the server (usually very small, but bad connections and long ping times can affect it).
- Time for the server to compile it (almost nothing if it's already cached).
- Time to execute and get the first result. Here is where it's complicated:

  - If the execution plan of the query contains a blocking operator, such as a Sort or Hash, then the first result can often take a long time.
  - If the plan has no blocking operators then the first result can often come back very quickly. But certain types of queries can be worse off, such as large analytical queries.
  - This is purely a rule of thumb: actual performance will depend on many things.
  - **The primary issue here, whether or not you have a blocking operator, is whether the query plan is good or not.** You need to analyze it and change as necessary. Most small queries should return in milliseconds if the tables are correctly indexed and the query is written well.
- Time for the server to respond with the first result (also usually small but subject to ping times).

The time to execute `reader.ReadAsync()` is purely the time taken to fetch the next row, which could be fast for a blocking plan or a small query, and slow for a big non-blocking one. Network speed may play a factor also, as can very large blobs of data. Ultimately reading a lot of data takes a lot of time.

---

As noted in the comments, `ConfigureAwait(false)` can also speed up context switches, although this is unlikely to make a huge difference on a database call.